# How do I get a value from the style element?

Tags: html, css, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How do I get a single value from the style element.

Here is my CSS. I want to be able to get the width value of 51.06383%

```
span id="ctl00_cphNavigation_svyNavigation_lblProgressMeter" class="progressmeter" style="display:inline-block;width:51.06383%;"
```

I retrieved the style value by using the below code. That returns the entire style value. I'm not sure how to separate it so I can just get the width.

```
driver.getSingleElement("css=span#ctl00_cphNavigation_svyNavigation_lblProgressMeter").getAttribute("style");`
```

Comment: What do you use to work with webdriver? The Java API? Can you show some more code surrounding that `driver` line? Are you familiar with basic string manipulation in whatever language you are using?

Comment: I am using Java to work with the webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I ended up creating the below method to grab the percentage.

```
protected void verifyProgressMeter(int expectedpercentage) {
    String progress1 = driver.getSingleElement(AppObjects.ProgressMeter).getAttribute("style");
    String progresswidth = progress1.substring(progress1.indexOf("width:") + 6, progress1.length() - 2);
    Double progress2 = new Double(progresswidth);
    Long actualpercentage = Math.round(progress2);
    Assert.assertEquals(actualpercentage.intValue(), expectedpercentage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style = driver.getSingleElement("css=span#ctl00_cphNavigation_svyNavigation_lblProgressMeter").getAttribute("style");
value = style.split("width:")[1].split(";")[0];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmc7B/

But, if you can, why not use `.style.width`?

Comment: Can you tell me what .style.width would be called in Selenium?